# Azure Python SDK to get cost of individual resources

Tags: python, azure, azure-python-sdk

I want to get cost of individual resources using python script is thr any way to get the price of VM,Database etc.,

Answer (score 0):

Use the Azure Billing library for Python.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/cost-management-+-billing?view=azure-python